# Converting Bitmap to RGB in VB

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing

Please see the attatched code below. I have managed to take a screenshot of my computing using VB and I have stored it as a bitmap. I want to convert this bitmap (quickly!) to an array of rgb values.

Any simple code that can do this?

Cheers
Martin

```
' Capture screen code
Dim bounds As Rectangle
Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
Dim graph As Graphics
bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

' Display the captured image
 Display.Image = screenshot
```

Comment: It already is an array.  You'll however have to write the code in C#, vb.net doesn't support pointers to truly take advantage of LockBits().

Answer (score 0):

An example is in the Bitmap.LockBits documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx#Y856

Comment: This does work, though it is very very slow ... I have over 900k values to copy and it takes ages... Any way to make it faster?